# Django python doesn't work about unapplied migration

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, migration

You have 3 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): news.
Run `'python manage.py migrate'` to apply them.

After I run this command and it gives me error.

python manage.py migrate

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 30, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 308, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)   File "/Users/danazholdykhairova/Desktop/original/bootcamp/config/settings/local.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .base import *  # noqa   File enter code here"/Users/danazholdykhairova/Desktop/original/bootcamp/config/settings/base.py", line 267emphasized text
    REDIS_URL = f'{env("REDIS_URL", default="redis://127.0.0.1:6379")}/{0}'
                                                                          ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You wrote an `f` as prefix, so Python aims to find a variable named `0`. What are you trying to do here (probably `settings.py` file)?

Comment: @willem-van-onsem if i run server with python3 manage runserver all works but it doesn't migrate changes with python3 migrate and says to do python migrate

Comment: You *should* be running it in Python 3. Recent versions of Django don't work in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

REDIS_URL variable is using an f-string - which was only introduced in python 3.6

Comment: It run server but doesn't migrate changes after runnig says to python migrate